# Haskell + Yesod: Separating insert logic using Persistent won't compile. Cannot figure out types

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm new to Haskell, coming from Scala. I like Haskell, but I feel like I'm fighting the type system when it comes to using `persistent`.

**My Request**: I'd like to separate some insert logic into its own method. I can't quite figure out the types, or the right way to do this. All my failed attempts won't compile. More succinct questions below.

Here is the data declaration:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Curator
  name String
  url String
  feed String
  UniqueUrl url
  deriving Show
Article
  url String
  title String
  content String
  curatorId CuratorId Eq
  deriving Show
|]
```

Here's a failed attempt that doesn't work:

```
insertArticle :: String -> String -> String -> MaybeT (???)
insertArticle url title content = do
    curatorId <- selectFirst [curatorName ==. "Fake Name"]
    lift $ do
        curator <- curatorId
        insert (Article url title content curator)
```

So, my questions:

1. What type should be in `???` ?
2. Is `lift` in the right place? (usually the compiler is more helpful).
3. Is there a better way to do this?

PS - I have successfully abstracted other logic away, e.g. The insert is just causing me a world of pain. I was unable to get it to compile while using `SqlPersistM`

```
getFeeds :: SqlPersistM [Curator]
getFeeds = do
  curatorIds <- selectList [] [Asc CuratorName]
  let curatorGenerics = map entityVal curatorIds
  let curators = map (\x -> x :: Curator) curatorGenerics
  return curators
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `insertArticle` should be `SqlPersistM (Maybe ArticleId)`, because it returns `Just` an inserted article id or `Nothing` in `SqlPersistM` monad.

You can implement the function something like:

```
insertArticle :: String -> String -> String -> SqlPersistM (Maybe ArticleId)
insertArticle url title content = do
    curatorEntity <- selectFirst [CuratorName ==. "Fake Name"] []
    for curatorEntity $ \(Entity curatorId _) ->
        insert (Article url title content curatorId)
```

I use `for` from `Data.Traversable` to handle the `Maybe` value `selectFirst` returns here.

But, actually, I don't like this type signature because it sticks to the sql backend. To make it more generalized, you can write a type annotation like this.

```
insertArticle :: (Applicative m, PersistQuery m, PersistMonadBackend m ~ PersistEntityBackend Curator) =>
                 String -> String -> String -> m (Maybe ArticleId)
```

The signature is a bit complex, but this function works with any backends.

By the way, your `getFeeds` can be simplified.

```
getFeeds :: (Functor m, PersistQuery m, PersistMonadBackend m ~ PersistEntityBackend Curator) =>
            m [Curator]
getFeeds = map entityVal <$> selectList [] [Asc CuratorName]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How did you find the type to be `SqlPersistT`? Whenever I ventured down the road of using the more general `insert` types I got got miserable, unreadable type issues. I'm still getting used to navigating hackage, so maybe I missed the `SqlPersistT`.
PS - Thanks for the improvement to `getFeeds`!

Comment: Follow-up: do you know where I can read more about the tilde (`~`) in the type signature? Is that saying that `PersistMonadBackend m` is in some kind of equivalence or family of `PersistEntityBackend Curator` ?

Comment: @weirdcanada: `a ~ b` is a type equality constraint, meaning the types `a` and `b` must be the same. The docs: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/equality-constraints.html

Comment: Take `getFeeds` as an example. We usually run this action using `runDB` inside handlers, so the concrete type of `getFeeds` should be `YesodDB App [Curator]`. If you take a look at the definition of `instance YesodPersist App`, you'll find that it's expanded to `SqlPersistT (HandlerT App IO) [Curator]`. That means this action will run in `SqlPersistT m` monad.

Comment: @snak thanks. I'm using this outside of the context of a yesod web-app, so that makes sense.

Comment: @Porges thanks for the link. I tried searching for tilde and it was difficult. I'll read those docs.